# tengo un error el react que me esta pasando esto soy nuevo agradezco su colaboracion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bucle-for, dom, label

estoy tratando de adapatra un formulario de bootstrap en react la como es que me da un eroor al tratar de renderizarlo.
react-dom.development.js:86

```
   Warning: Invalid DOM property `for`. Did you mean `htmlFor`?
at label
at div
at div
at DirecEnvio
at form
at div
at div
at main
at div
at div
at CheckoutBox (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:662:56)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error comunmente sucede porque en `for` es una palabra reservada en la sintaxis de `JSX`.

Probablemente estas usando una etiqueta `label` para un `input` y estas usando la palabra resevada `for`. En su lugar debes usar `htmlFor` la propiedad para asociar tu `input` con el `label`.

Probablemente lo tienes asi:

```
 <label for="exampleInput">Example label</label>
 <input type="text" maxLength={50} required className="form-control" id="exampleInput"/>
```

Reemplazalo por

```
<label htmlFor="exampleInput">Example label</label>//Aca esta la diferencia
<input type="text" maxLength={50} required className="form-control" id="exampleInput"/>
```

Por [aca](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) dejo la documentacion DOM elements in react

Comment: Hola Gracias por tu comentario ya lo he cambiado funciona bien.

Comment: si te sirvio recuerda que puedes aceptar mi respuesta ✓✓.

Comment: tengo otro inconveniente al validar el forms me lo validad solo una vez despues me recarga la pagina estoy usando un ckeckout form de bootstrap

Comment: @LisandroReinozo para poder ayudarte debes formular una nueva pregunta, redacta una nueva pregunta y agrega los detalles necesarios, lee [ask]